# How to process click event of dynamically created hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically generated links like

`<a name="details" id="1" href="javascript:;">Details</a>`

When one of them clicked I want to process this event with javascript code like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = document.getElementsByName('details').item(0);

    a.on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            ///
        });
    });
});
```

However, even though it seems to find hyperlinks quite perfectly, on click event it doesn't enter the function.

What is wrong with the implementation?

Comment: use `$(document).on('click','a', function() {` delegate the click to document

Comment: @guardio Would I be able to access id property of the hyperlink using this implementation?

Comment: yes by using `$(this).attr('id')` you will get the clicked anchor's id

Answer (score -1):

`on` is a method you find on jQuery objects.

`document.getElementsByName('details').item(0)` returns a native DOM element.

Either use `addEventListener` instead of `on` or `$("some selector")` instead of `getElementsByName` & `item`.